# What is the best practice to consume Azure table storage in a windows store app?

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

I'm using PRISM framework to develop my App, there is no Patterns and practice guidance available on consuming Azure table with Windows store app?

What is the best practice to consume Azure table storage in a windows store app?

1. App calling WCF REST service which then talks to Azure table through Azure SDK
2. App calling Azure table storage REST service
3. App calling Azure mobile service which then talks to Azure table through data script
4. App consuming Azure table storage through Azure SDK

Any other option?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any guidance available on the best practices for consuming Azure Table Storage with Windows Store App.

Given your 4 options above, I would not recommend using #2 and #4 ***as is*** for one reason - In order for you to use any of these options, you would need to include your storage credentials (account name/account key) in your application itself which I think is a big security risk.

There's one other way by which you can use #2 and #4 and that's by using [`Shared Access Signature (SAS)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn140255.aspx) functionality. Essentially you create SAS tokens using some kind of server side code (WCF/Mobile Service/Web API etc.) and provide that SAS token to your client application. Then you can use #2 or #4 approach.

The advantage with this approach to me is that your server-side component is really light weight as all it is doing is creating SAS tokens and your Windows 8 application is directly talking with storage service without the need of an intermediary. Given that Windows Azure Table Storage now supports JSON, the data transferred between your app and storage will be very minimal (compared to ATOMPUB XML format which was really bulky).